# What is a good way to make a polymorph Task interface in c++?

Tags: c++, architecture, polymorphism

What is a good way to make a polymorph Task interface?
I want to design an interface for a processing library, which takes different data objects.

- All data objects inherit from a `IDataObject` class.
- The objects should be passed to the task throug a `setInput(IDataObject* input)` function.
- I want to be able to define which kind of data object is needed. Maybe through a function `setRequieredInput(DataObjectBase* input)`.
- It should be possible to find `Tasks` which are able to process a data object maybe like this `vector<Task*> getTasks(DataObjectBase* input)`. Like a Microkernel (Dependency Container)?

All suggestions are welcome.

I listed an first shoot below:

```
class IDataObject {
   // Visitor style implementation
   virtual void multiDispatch(Task* task) = 0;
}
class ISingleAccessDataObject : IDataObject {
   // Visitor style implementation
   // would this work orcan't I use the definition derived 
   // virtual function for the "interface" and class?
   // If I'm right this is the diamond problem (inheriting the same
   // function twice).
   virtual void multiDispatch(Task* task) = 0; 
   double getData(int i) = 0;
}
class DataObjectBase : IDataObject {
   // Visitor style implementation
   virtual void multiDispatch(Task* task) {
      task->execute(this);
   }  
   // ...  
}

class DataObjectBase {
   // Visitor style implementation
   virtual void multiDispatch(Task* task) {
      task->execute(this);
   }   
   // ... 
}
class DerivedDataObject : DataObjectBase, ISingleAccessDataObject  {
   // Visitor style style Implementation
   virtual void multiDispatch(Task* task) {
      task->execute(this);
   }
   // ...
}
class Task {
   void setInput(DataObjectBase* input) {
      if (checkCanHandle(input) {
         m_inputs.push_back(input);
      }
   }
   void execute() {
      for (int i = 0; i < m_Inputs.size(); i++) {
         IDataObject* dataObject = m_Inputs.at(i);
         if (dataObject == NULL) {
            continue;
         }
         //-----------------------
         // Visitor style implementation
         dataObject.multiDispatch(this);
         //-----------------------
         // or
         //-----------------------
         if (Derived1DataObject* derived1DataObject = dynamic_cast<Derived1DataObject>(dataObject )) {
            // ...
         } else if (ISingleAccessDataObject* singleAccessDataObject = dynamic_cast<SingleAccessDataObject>(dataObject)) {
            // ...
         } else { //Log error }
         //-----------------------
      }
   }
   // Visitor style implementation
   //-----------------------
   // This would require to know all DataObjects on defining the
   // Task "Interface". What is not really what I want.
   void execute(Derived1DataObject* input) {
      // ..
   }
   void execute(Derived2DataObject* input) {
      // ..
   }
   void execute(ISingleIndexAccessDataObject* input) {
      // ..
   }
   //-----------------------
   bool checkCanHandle(DataObjectBase* input) {
      for (int i = 0; i < m_HandleDataObjects.size(); i++) {
         // Question: Is there a way to let this be true if 
         // m_HandleDataObjects.at(i) is a super class of input?
         // Question: Is there a way to allow only save something like 
         // the typeid. Maybe name, but I'm not sure if name is the best
         // option.
         if (typeid(m_HandleDataObjects.at(i)) == typeid(input)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }


   vector<DataObjectBase*> m_HandleDataObjects;
   vector<DataObjectBase*> m_Inputs;
}
class TaskRegister {
   vector<Task*> getTasks(IDataObject* input) {
      vector<Task*> ret;
      for (int i = 0; i < m_Tasks.size(); i++) {
         // Question: Is there a better way using a HashMap or something else
         if (m_Tasks.at(i).checkCanHandle(input)) {
            ret.push_back(m_Tasks.at(i));
         }
      }   
      return ret;    
   }
   vector<Task*> m_Tasks;
}
```

Comment: Hope the question isn't to general. But if I seperate it in more questions, I think my intention wouldn't get clear.